# Found object returns Nothing despite being set within an "If not ... is nothing" check

Tags: excel, vba, find

I am trying to find a string in a row and then select the found cell. For this I have the following part of code:

```vb
currentRelease = Worksheets("Summary").Cells(5, "I").Value
Set myrange = Worksheets("Summary").Rows(15)

If Not myrange.Find(currentRelease, lookat:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
    Set releaseFound = myrange.Find(currentRelease, lookat:=xlValues) 'this row gets executed
    releaseFound.Select
End If
```

I am not getting any error, but when debugging no cell gets selected and I see that the `releaseFound` is returning `Nothing` although the `Set releaseFound...` row of this code gets executed, so the `If` check has been actually positive? What could be the reason for this?
I tried to use the `Find` feature on the sheet, outside of VBA, and the value is really found where I am searching for it...

Comment: make  sure you use the `.Cells` reference correct. `"I"` corrosponds to a text

Comment: `lookat` accepts `xlWhole` or `xlPart`. `xlValues` goes into `LookIn`. I assume you have `on error resume next` before this code, you should really remove that. There is no reason to execute the search twice though. Do `Set releaseFound = myrange.Find(currentRelease, LookIn:=xlValues)` and then see if `releaseFound` is `Nothing`.

Comment: @GSerg, thanks very much. I had mistaken LookIn and LookAt. With LookIn:=xlValues it is working properly :)

Answer (score 1):

### A Find Method Example

- [`Range.Find method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub FindMethodTest()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Summary")
    
    ' Try to restrict this declaration to a string or a numeric value.
    Dim SearchValue As Variant: SearchValue = ws.Cells(5, "I").Value
    
    Dim SearchRange As Range: Set SearchRange = ws.Rows(15)
    
    ' Use a variable to reference the found cell.
    Dim FirstFoundCell As Range
    ' To start the search with the first cell 'A15', you need to set
    ' the 'After' parameter to the last cell in row '15'.
    Set FirstFoundCell = SearchRange.Find( _
        What:=SearchValue, After:=SearchRange.Cells(SearchRange.Cells.Count), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        
    ' Now test the variable.
    If Not FirstFoundCell Is Nothing Then ' found
        FirstFoundCell.Select
        Debug.Print "The first found value is in cell '" _
            & FirstFoundCell.Address(0, 0) & "'."
    Else ' not found
        Debug.Print "Value not found."
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion by @GSerg in the comments above solved the issue: lookat accepts xlWhole or xlPart. xlValues goes into LookIn.
The code now works for me:

```
currentRelease = Worksheets("Summary").Cells(5, "I").Value
Set myrange = Worksheets("Summary").Rows(15)

If Not myrange.Find(currentRelease, lookin:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
    Set releaseFound = myrange.Find(currentRelease, lookin:=xlValues) 'this row gets executed
    releaseFound.Select
End If
```